# Combinatorial search by testing sets with fixed number of elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am struggling to see the complexity of the following combinatorial search problem. Could anyone help me?

Consider a set $I$ of $n$ items known to contain $d$ defectives or less. Assume $d < n/2$. One chooses a set $S$ with exactly $n-d$ items in each test. If the set $S$ has no defectives, then the test function $f(S)=1$, otherwise $f(S)=0$. How many tests would one need to know which items are defectives?

Comment: A nondeterministic Turing machine can do it in $d+1$ tests.

Comment: @MattS Thank you for your answer! Is it implies that finding all defectives can be achieved in polynomial time on $n$ when $d=\gamma n$ for some friction $\gamma\in(0,1/2)$? In other words, does this search problem belong to the complexity class $\mathbf P$?

Comment: I can totally prove it's in $\mathbf{NP}$. Sure, $\mathbf{P}$ is harder to prove, but this is a MATH forum! Who cares how fast as long as it can be done? (kidding, I'm thinking about it)

Comment: @MattS Thanks. Your result on $\mathbf{NP}$ is a very interesting fact for me. But this actually arises from an engineering problem, so it would be better to belong to $\mathbf{P}$. (Sorry that here is a math forum, not engeneering forum!)

Comment: I don't think this problem is in P. It seems like the only time $f(S)$ returns $1$ is if we have $S$ exactly to be the set of non-defective items. We have $\binom{n}{d}$ ways to pick $n-d$ items, and amongst these, only of them makes $f$ returns 1, and the rest returns 0. I would think that we need $\Omega(\binom{n}{d})$ tests in the worst case.

Comment: Thank you, Irvan. Can one utilize some information of $f(S)=0$ after each test? If not, we must apply the brute force approach, and hence this problem is not in $\mathbf{P}$.